# presentar datos de varias tablasmysql en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

mi preguenta es la siguiente
tengo un codigo html en el cual quiero que ese muestren unos datos, para ello me dijeron que debia crear una tabla auxiliar para relacionar esos datos y presentarlos el codigo seria el siguiente

```
if(empty($buscador)){
$consulta= "SELECT*FROM curso_tiene_alumno";
$datos= mysql_query($consulta);


while($fila= mysql_fetch_assoc($datos)){

?>
<tr id="tr1">  
    <td><?php echo $fila ['curso_idcurso']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['alumno_idalumno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['clientes_codcliente']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['teorica']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['practica']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['simulacro']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['gwo_global']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['global']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="c_modificatipo_curso.php?filtrar=<?php echo $fila ['alumno_idalumno']?>&submit=buscar" id="buton">modificar</a></td>
    <td><a href="c_eliminatipo_curso.php?filtrar=<?php echo $fila ['alumno_idalumno']?>&submit=buscar" id="buton">eliminar</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
} else{
    $consulta2= "SELECT*FROM curso_tiene_alumno WHERE curso_idcurso LIKE '%$buscador%' "
            . "OR alumno_idalumno LIKE '%$buscador%' "
            . "OR clientes_codcliente LIKE '%$buscador%' "
            . "OR teorica LIKE '%$buscador%' "
            . "OR practica LIKE '%$buscador%' "
            . "OR simulacro LIKE '%$buscador%' "
            . "OR gwo_global LIKE '%$buscador%' "
            . "OR global LIKE '%$buscador%' ";

    $datos2= mysql_query($consulta2);

 while($fila= mysql_fetch_array($datos2)){
?> 
<tr id="tr2">
    <td><?php echo $fila ['curso_idcurso']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['alumno_idalumno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['clientes_codcliente']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['teorica']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['practica']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['simulacro']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['gwo_global']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila ['global']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="c_modificavincula_curso.php?filtrar=<?php echo $fila ['alumno_idalumno']?>&submit=buscar" id="buton">modificar</a></td>
    <td><a href="c_eliminavincula_curso.php?filtrar=<?php echo $fila ['alumno_idalumno']?>&submit=buscar" id="buton">eliminar</a></td>
</tr> 


<?php
 }    

?>
```

mi pregunta es como podria hacer para cambiar

```
<td><?php echo $fila ['curso_idcurso']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila ['alumno_idalumno']; ?></td>
```

y que en vez de aparecer el id aparezca el nombre o la referencia que tengo en las otras tablas.

Comment: Hola!!! Si no entendí mal podes traer ese dato en la sql que hagas, con algún inner join. La idea es que traigas los datos necesarios en la sql y luego recorras el recordset y muestres los datos en una tabla

Comment: Lo correcto es lanzar una sola consulta, no `n` consultas cuántas filas coincidan, lo cual sería absurdo. La consulta única quedaría más o menos así: `SELECT a.ID, ca.IDAlumno FROM alumno a INNER JOIN curso_tiene_alumno ca ON a.ID=ca.IDAlumno WHERE ca.curso_idcurso LIKE '%$buscador%' OR a.alumno_idalumno LIKE '%$buscador%' ` etc. aquí se asume que `alumno` tiene una columna `ID` que se relaciona en la otra tabla con `IDAlumno`. Observa que en las columnas se usa siempre el *alias* de cada tabla. Otra cosa revisa tu convención de nombres, parece demasiado engorrosa: `alumno_idalumno`, etc.

Comment: ¡Hola Dan! ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y colocar de que otra tabla deseas consultar los datos?